# Adding more debugging on a customer machine

Tags: version-control, versioning

Looking for suggestions on what to do for the following scenario: one of our customer has a problem but we can't reproduce it.  We need to send a couple of DLLs modified with more debugging information to him to get the data to be able to fix the problem.

The argument we are having is:

1. we should not release a hotfix with these DLLS but simply send the
   files (un-versioned) and then later release the official hotfix with the fix and the files versioned accordingly. Conclusion: It's not a big deal to give them files not released and versioned correctly
2. we should release the hotfix officially with just the debug info, send the files versioned correctly. When we have a fix, roll back the logging from the release branch and release the hotfix with the fix.  Conclusion: Do everything using official versions

Answer (score 1):

suggestion:

1. establish a debug build. this is just the same revision but with debug symbols and logging *enabled* (this is a feature flag, not a feature branch — cf. [branch by abstraction](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BranchByAbstraction.html)).
2. support then can have these at hand to assist understanding the issue the customer has with the software (debugging on site).
3. support channels back the needed information for the reproducer.
4. assignee on the issue reproduces.
5. assignee on the issue adds the regression test.
6. build and ship the next increment.
7. support then can have the next increment without the debug information and validate on the customer side.
8. if the error persists, continue at 2. just with the next increment debug build.
9. if support confirms working, mark this in the issue.
10. after the customer confirms working (there should be at least one day between if not longer) then it confirms the confirmed working of the support engineer.

case closed. gaps in the own build pipeline closed (missing debug build, missing regression test), processes improved and responsive support to customers that are running into a problem with your software regardless it's your fault or theirs. no needless discussions in the team about anything that is not the issue at hand.

the other solution is to release the source and build instructions, then let the customer debug it their own and channel feedback directly to development. this depends on the customer, and seems actually not applicable in your situation otherwise there would be no discussion about binary build artifacts and how to mix and match the things.

in general better identify the actual problem that lays within your development procedure (because that is what you can control) instead of "solutions" and all their "variants" that can only dance around the pudding. eat the pudding instead while the customer enjoys support.